# Editor Declined Invitation is a bad thing?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, editors

I recently submitted an article to an Elsevier journal and under the current status, it says: *"Editor Declined Invitation"*.  What does this mean?  Will this result in a rejection or is there another reason for this?

Comment: @Buffy I looked but it does not discuss this particular status (or how this fits in to the workflow exactly) in that post

Comment: @Catologist_who_flies_on_Monday Why don't you email the journal itself and ask?

Comment: I do not see how the generic answer to the generic question deals with this.  (Probably this is still a duplicate.)  Sometimes an error is made with in picking the editor to handle the paper.  I do not see this a reason to bother the journal.

Comment: I also don't quite see this as easily/obviously answered by the linked-to discussion. And, I'd comment that it's not a _good_ sign if the managing editor's first pick for editor for the paper declined. Yes, it could be just a subject matter mis-match, but, also, it could be an implicit judgement. No way to tell without seeing the people involved and the paper itself...

Comment: Fair, I had a feeling that the paper may have been too "mathematical" for the journal I submitted to; so I'm also included to think its an implicit judgement.  Thanks for the advice all (and Paul).

Comment: I reopened the question since this status is not in the linked question.

Comment: @Allure, perhaps you should have added your answer here to the canonical answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after your manuscript is submitted, [this happens](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like):

> ## Editor assignment or invitation
>
> Based on the topic of the manuscript and suggestions by the authors, an editor is assigned to handle the manuscript. Depending on the journal, the assignment may be done by technical staff, the journal's chief editor, or automatic by submission category or author suggestion. With some journals, editors are invited and not assigned.

And at this stage the editor invited declined.

What does it mean? There're many possibilities:

- The editor is currently busy and not able to handle submissions.
- Whoever made the invitation thought the paper was in the editor's field, but it isn't.
- The editor knows one of the authors of the manuscript personally and is therefore declining due to conflict of interest.

Could it be your manuscript is terrible and the editor therefore declines to handle it? It's possible, but more standard here would be to agree to handle it and then desk reject. If it happens I would guess that the invited editor is not experienced with the editorial management system.

In any case there's nothing to do except wait.